# CSS positioning absolute With point of reference

Tags: html, css

I have two divs inside each other one `relative` the other is `absolute` and positioned `right: -35` so it over pass the relative div with `-35`

now it was calculated as -35 with `- Name` 
if the length of the text (`inside #sub`) is increased it will move over the text (`hello everyone.`) and why? because it is position `right`.

it will look like this

```
hello everyone. -Name
```

html:

```
<div id="main">
    <span>hello everyone.
    <span id="sub">-Name</span>
</div>
```

code:

```
#main {position: relative; display: inline-block;}
#sub {
    position: absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right: -35;
}
```

There is another solution which changing `right` to `left`. But it will involved javascript so I can get the length of the div `main` since it will not always be `hello everyone.` than I add lenth.div + 35 to solve this.

Is here a way to maintain `right: -35`, and change the expanding of the `span` to right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to use `left:100%` on your absolute positioned span element. I *think* this is the result you wanted. Also, I fixed your HTML by adding the closing tag for the first `<span>` element.

```css
#main {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
#sub {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  min-width: fit-content;
  left: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <span>hello everyone.</span>
  <span id="sub">-Name</span>
</div>
```